# How to connect wit-php with facebook messenger?

Tags: php, facebook-messenger, wit-ai

I am following this tutorial [Wi-php tutorial](https://github.com/tgallice/wit-php-example)
and i can available test as this tuotrial.I am thinking that,to connect with facebook messenger.Is it possible to connect facebook messenger by using this tuorial code.
Please guide me.Thanks